# Rails with Devise & Omniauth - multiple social media login providers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations, omniauth

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I am trying to set up devise with omniauth and each of Facebook, linkedin, twitter and googleauth. Im currently trying to follow this tutorial.

http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/

I have models called:

user.rb, profile.rb and identity.rb

The associations are:

User

```
has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy

has_many :identities, dependent: :destroy
```

Profile

```
belongs_to :user
```

Identity

```
belongs_to :user
```

Identity also validates:

```
validates_presence_of :uid, :provider
validates_uniqueness_of :uid, :scope => :provider
```

I am trying to make a partial in my user views folder that lists out each of the optional authentication methods and shows whether a user has used them to connect or if not, providing a link to connect them.

I have made:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">

                    <tr>
                      <td><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></td>   
                      <td>
                        <% if @profile.user.identity.provider == 'facebook' %>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"</span>
                        <% else %>  
                            <%= link_to icon('Connect Facebook', id: 'facebookauth'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
                        <% end %>   

                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td><i class="fa fa-google"></i></td> 
                      <td>
                        <% if @user.identity.provider includes 'googleauth' %>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"</span>
                        <% else %>  
                            <%= link_to icon('Connect Google', id: 'googleauth'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %>
                        <% end %>   

                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></td>   
                      <td>
                        <% if @user.identity.provider includes 'linkedin' %>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"</span>
                        <% else %>  
                            <%= link_to icon('Connect Linkedin', id: 'linkedinauth'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:linkedin) %>
                        <% end %>

                      </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                      <td><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></td>    
                      <td>
                        <% if @user.identity.provider includes 'twitter' %>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"</span>
                        <% else %>  
                            <%= link_to icon('Connect Twitter', id: 'twitterauth'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter) %>
                        <% end %>

                      </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

I want to show this partial in the profile edit form.

```
<div class="formheader">Update your profile</div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <%= render 'form' %>
            <%= render 'users/authentication' %>

        </div>
      </div>
```

I can't figure out how to write the chain so that when a user updates their profile, they can connect other social media accounts to their identity.

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

I've tried a few different things to get these chains linked including:

```
<% if @profile.user.identity.provider == 'facebook' %>
<% if @current_user.profile.identity.provider == 'facebook' %>
<% if @user.profile.identity.provider == 'facebook' %>
```

Im just guessing with this - I can't figure it out. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: ok sorry if I don't give much explanation here but hopefully you'll find answers here : https://github.com/charly/omnidevisable

Comment: Hi Charly. Thanks for this. I've been struggling to figure this out for about 3 years. I'm going to give this approach another shot before I dump it and try something else, but I've read your blog and thank you for sharing. It's in my bookmarks if I ditch everything I've tried so far and start again (which would only be about the 30th time I've done that to this point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User.identity won't work since User `has_many` Identities.

You may do something like `@user.identities.map(&:provider).include?('facebook')`

Comment: Hi, I tried this originally but forgot the question mark and didn't know about map. Thanks for this. I get an error when I try this:   <% if @user.identities.map(:&provider).include?('facebook') %>. The error says:syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' . I know that error message means a ')' is missing, but I can't see where I should add one. It looks right to me.

Comment: @user2860931my bad, I've updated my answer. It should be `&:provider` not `:&provider`

Comment: Thanks. That error has stopped appearing. Now I get another one that says: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with 'id'=authentications. Can you see what might be causing that?

Comment: @user2860931 looks like you're passing the string "authentications" as a value for params[:id]. It'd be better if you'd create a new question and add the controller code.